# is it possible to handle 2 variable to changing if/else condition is true on ES6?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, ecmascript-6

Let say I have a code like this

```
var a, b;
b = 1;
var c = b > 0 ? a = 1 /*and c = 2*/ : a = 0 /*and c = 1*/;
console.log(a + c);
```

Is there any way to make `c = 2` and `a = 1` with above code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can wrap the expression inside the ternary with brackets, and use the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) to return the number you want to assign to `c`.

```js
var a, b = 1
var c = b > 0 ? (a=1, 2) : (a=0, 1)

console.log(a, c)
```

With ES6 you can use [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to assign the numbers to `a` and `c`:

```js
const b = 1
const [a, c] = b > 0 ? [1, 2] : [0, 1]

console.log(a, c)
```

Comment: looks like just add a simple sign and worked, have tried to use `{}` sign but no luck, lol, need 10 min to accepted answer

Comment: @flix - I've added another "more ES6" way of doing that.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternate to @[Ori Drori](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5157454/ori-drori)'s answer, you can even try something like this:

```js
var b = 1
var a = b > 0 ? 1 : 0;
var c = b + a;

console.log(a, c)
```

Comment: **Note:** Ori's answer is preferred but as per given information/code, you can also try this approach. This is simpler to read. But if you think there is anything incorrect/inappropriate with this answer, please share your feedback as comment along with your vote

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend an old-fashioned

```
var a, c, b = 1;
if (b > 0) {
  a = 1;
  c = 2;
} else {
  a = 0
  c = 1;
}
console.log(a + c);
```

If your specific case allows it, you might also do

```
var a = b > 0 ? 1 : 0;
var c = a + 1;
```

If you're looking for a way to assign multiple values to multiple variables at once, ES6 destructuring is the solution:

```
var {a, c} = b > 0 ? {a: 1, c: 2} : {a: 0, c: 1};
```

Answer (score 0):

One more trick is using below code block

```
var a,b,c;
b=1;
b > 0 ? ((a=1) && (c = 2)) : ((c = 1) && (a=0));
alert(a + "   " + c);
```

This is the methodology used by the code minifier in Javascript. Such type of statements should be used with precautions. Let me explain how it works

**Case b = 1**

the condition `b > 0` is `true`. So the first part is evaluated. It has 2 parts with `&&` separated. It means both statements will get evaluated because first statement evaluates to`true` (unless first statenent returns `false`, this is where precaution is needed). Assigning value to some variable returns the same value. So this test case passes.

**Case b = -1**

the condition `b > 0` fails. Again we have 2 statements concatinated with `&&`, so both statements again gets evaluates. Here you see that I have placed `a = 0` as second statement. This is because when I assign `a = 0` it will return assigned value that is `0` and in Javascript `true = 1` and `false = 0`. So placing it as first statement will lead to unevaluated second statement.

Hope you understand the scenario and usage care.

The most pretty forward way without confusion would be using comma operator as mentioned in previous answers

```
var a,b,c;
b=1;
b > 0 ? (a=1, c = 2) : (a = 0, c = 1);
alert(a + "   " + c);
```

The `&&` and `,` technique is used by code minifier altogether.

Answer (score 0):

DRY coding requires;

```js
var a,
    b = 1;
var c = (b > 0 ? a = 1 : a = 0) + 1;
console.log(a + c);
```